# How to retrieve the document that's just been added in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I am using python and mongoengine for this project.
And i am creating a restAPI. Since save() query in mongo inserts new or updates existing document.

```
SearchRating(stars=4, comment='').save()   // returns "None" on success
```

This particular piece of code in mongoengine only creates new document. However the idea is that only once user is suppose to create this document, later they should only update it. But for updation i need to know what _id i just added in mongodb in search_rating collection.

So how shall i know the _id of document that i just added?

Comment: In the callback that is sent back post addition to the database.

Comment: You can also take a look at the option where a record is updated if it exists and created if it doesn't (if you can uniquely identify it based on set of datapoints.)

Comment: callback returns 'None' when successfully added. This is why i am stuck here...

Comment: use `insert` instead, it has what you want. http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.insert

Comment: Yeah this insert is actually able to provide me created id :D . i assumed this also wouldn't work so i didn't try it before. Thanks man

Comment: Also create in mongoengine also retrieves the document id. http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.create

Comment: That is what I meant, document id of inserted document. I am glad I could help, all the best.